# How to install pocketsphinx , and sphinxbase . and use them in java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Me abhi I downloaded the zip files of the pocketsphinx and sphinxbase . And I want to use them in netbeans please help me . as it is a school project and I want to perform best iin my class. I have downloaded the both pocketsphinx and sphinxbase as zip files . I have imported them both zips in the IDE . But I learned  that  I have to install them , please tell me how to do this .  please

Comment: As this is homework it is a rule on this site that says: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic point #3. We are more than happy to help you with performing the best in your class, but you have to do work, not just come here and ask like you have just done. Please edit your question when you have done research (use google) and have tried to solve it yourself first then show us what you did.

Comment: Sir I have researched on speech

Comment: Please tell me how to install

Comment: And I also imported both the files in Netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: You should add that detail to your question by clicking on `edit` just below your question. That will allow people who would be able to help you to see it and help.

Comment: Thanks for the details about this site. As I m new don't know the rules

Comment: where did you download them from?

Comment: I did that from sourceforge.net

Comment: Read the instructions at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pocketsphinx and Sphinxbase are libraries that you unpack to the appropriate area of your system where you do your development work. It is system dependant and a few other things. As you downloaded from sourceforge, the place to get the instructions is from the sourceforge page for this product which is http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx. Briefly, the install procedure according to the page linked to is:

> Pocketsphinx is a library that depends on another library called
>   SphinxBase which provides common functionality across all CMUSphinx
>   projects. To install Pocketsphinx, you need to install both
>   Pocketsphinx and Sphinxbase. It's possible to use Pocketsphinx both in
>   Linux, Windows, on MacOS, iPhone and Android.
>
> First of all, download the released packages pocketsphinx and
>   sphinxbase from project downloads, checkout them from subversion or
>   github. For more details see download page.